# Call to base class method: accessing member of derived class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Say we have two classes:

```
class Parent
{
public:
   vector<int> x;
protected:
   void Method();
}
```

and

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
   vector<double> x;
}
```

and the method `Method()` operates on `x` and makes some operation, which is compatible for both types `int` and `double`:

```
void Parent::Method() 
{ 
    x.push_back(1); 
}
```

Then, if I will create an instance of `Child` class, initialize `vector<double> x`, and then call derived method `Method()` from the base class, C++ will try to operate on `Parent`'s member `x` and not the `Child`'s one. Is there any way how to make base class method to automatically operate on the member that belongs to created class, `Child`'s `vector<int> x`?

**EDIT:**
As McAden correctly noted, this behavior can be easily achieved using polymorphism: three classes - 1 base and 2 derived. But does it mean that it is impossible with just 2 classes?

Comment: Do you actually want `Child` to have two vectors hanging around, or do you really intend for there to only be one vector?

Comment: I create only `Child`-type object and want only `Child`'s vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to create instances of `Child` and you want the `Child` to dictate the type of the vector, this problem is more naturally solved with a template `Parent`. As a simple example, `Parent` could be parameterized by what `vector<>` should contain:

```
template <typename T>
class Parent {
public:
    std::vector<T> x;
protected:
    void Method () { x.push_back(1); }
};

class Child : public Parent<double> {
    //...
};
```

If you actually have many such things you want the child to control in the `Parent`, then you probably should treat `Child` more like a traits class for the `Parent`. Thus, `Parent` would actually be parameterized by its `Child`, and your code would then be using [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). which provides "static polymorphism".

```
template <typename CHILD>
class Parent {
protected:
    void Method () {
        CHILD *child = static_cast<CHILD *>(this);
        child->x.push_back(1);
    }
};

class Child : public Parent<Child> {
public:
    std::vector<double> x;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! What is `T` is a complex type such as class?

Comment: If you are talking about the first example of code, if `T` is complex, likely trying to use `Method()` would fail, unless there was a conversion from `int` to the class `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Changing data types in dealing with inheritance isn't so much possible with the exception being cases where covariance is used. If you want to make a class that handles differing data types what you're probably looking for is a template class:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/143-template-classes/

Comment: Yes, you need to use virtual functions to allow polymorphism

Comment: @McAden, yes, you are right - the behvaiour that I want can be implemented with three classes - one base and two derived. But I wanted to see if it is possible with just 2 classes. Thanks

Comment: What if the types of `x` are different as in the above example?

Comment: Didn't notice you were going for that. With the exception of covariance, no.

Comment: x is a member variable, `Method` is void

Comment: "With the exception of covariance, no." Could you please explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Wanting differing data types `virtual` isn't what you're looking for. It's template classes.